# App submission response: "Post-dated Code Signature"

Tags: macos, ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, timezone

I uploaded my app yesterday.  Its status turned to "Waiting for Review" from "Upload Received" today, but I have also received this e-mail:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "MyAppName". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct
>   the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Post-dated Code Signature. Code signature identified by
>   'mybundle.myapp' in bundle 'mybundle.myapp' has a timestamp of
>   '2013-09-04T06:13:09.000-07:00', but it was submitted to the App Store
>   at '2013-09-04T08:48:41.552-07:00'. This might indicate that your
>   system clock is not set to the correct timezone.
>
> If you would like to update your binary for this app, you can reject
>   this binary from the Binary Details page in iTunes Connect. Note that
>   rejecting your binary will remove your app from the review queue and
>   the review process will start over from the beginning when you
>   resubmit your binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

What does this e-mail mean? Will my app be rejected? Should I re-upload my app?

Answer (score 2):

Seems straightforward enough, the app you uploaded has a timestamp that indicates your machines time is incorrect (namely according to the stamps it was built *after* you submitted it), so either you have a time machine, or just the wrong time set.  They are just letting you know, and allowing you the chance to correct the issue and resubmit if you like.  It doesn't read as a rejection to me.

Comment: The submission timestamp looks to me to be about 2:35 after the signing timestamp, not before.  Am I missing an important digit somewhere?  The offsets are even the same.

Comment: @zigg I don't think you're missing anything - it's odd, but perhaps the copy paste was wrong or there's a bug in Apple's date formatter and it was really post dated - just not that we would agree from looking at the text. The main thing is - it's purely a warning and the upload was successful and things will go through normal review without needing any changes.